# Has anyone compiled eSpeak Text-to-Speech?

Tags: 11.10, text-to-speech

I have used Ubuntu as the OS for about 1.5 years on our desktop.

I am also dyslexic so the eSpeak text reader is a huge Help!

I put the 11.10 Ubuntu on our AMD 64 laptop.
espeak doesn't work on 11.10.

MS Windows has great freeware to do this, try "ReadPlease 2003"
however ReadPlease 2003 is for Window only and will NOT run in Wine.

If someone has does so or could explain to be how to compile the source for eSpeak so that it could run on 11.10 Ubuntu i'd be grateful??

Comment: eSpeak at http://espeak.sourceforge.net/ ? Did it work for older versions? What is the error in Ubuntu 11.10 if you try to compile it?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu should already have Orca installed. Press ALT+F2 to access to the Launcher and type 'Orca', it should be there.